# How to return the last value in the dictionary which satisfies the condition

Tags: python, dictionary

The code should keep looking up the keys until a key is reached that has no
corresponding value. Only then that key should be returned. If a key is not available during the tracing or when it is not found, the last key must be returned.

I have traced till the final key/ value pair using recursion, but I'm not able to return the final traced value.

```
def rabbit_hole(d, word):    
    for key,val in d.items():    
        if key == word:    
            return rabbit_hole(d,val)

d = {"bat": "pig", "pig": "cat", "cat": "dog", "dog": "ant",
     "cow": "bee", "bee": "elk", "elk": "fly", "ewe": "cod",
     "cod": "hen", "hog": "fox", "fox": "jay", "jay": "doe",
     "rat": "ram", "ram": "rat"}
```

`print(rabbit_hole(d, "bat"))`

Expected result: ant
Actual result: None (as im unable to return the last value "ant" in this case)

Answer (score 0):

An important concept in a recursive function (which you've made) is the base case. The base case is what stops the recursion and closes the call stack back up. In your function, if no key is found, the function doesn't return any value which in python means it evaluates to `None`.

What you should do is end the function with a `return word` outside the loop, that way if the function doesn't return inside the loop you just return the last word found.

Also, unrelated to the question but a good note. You're defeating the purpose of a dictionary by looping through the items. What you should do instead is check if the word you're looking for is in the dictionary, then use a key accessor, or use `.get()` for example:

```
if word in d:
   val = d[word]
```

or

```
val = d.get(word)
if val is not None:
    return val
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for -

```
dum = []    

def rabbit_hole(dic, word):    
    dum.append(word)

    if len(dum)>len(dic):
        print("Hey! this input is not right, there's no end to it..")
        return

    for key,val in dic.items():    
        if key == word:    
            return rabbit_hole(dic, val)
    return word

d = {"bat": "pig", "pig": "cat", "cat": "dog", "dog": "ant",
     "cow": "bee", "bee": "elk", "elk": "fly", "ewe": "cod",
     "cod": "hen", "hog": "fox", "fox": "jay", "jay": "doe",
     "rat": "ram", "ram": "mouse"}

print(rabbit_hole(d,"bat"))
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried that, but when the word which I pass to the function is "rat" (i.e.) print(rabbit_hole(d, "rat")), the output enters an infinite loop. So is there any way to possibly say it has occurred before and return False if the same key-value pair repeats? @Imtiaz Ahmed

Comment: It's because in your code there is a mistake `"rat": "ram", "ram": "rat"`.... so it is an infinite loop. So, I had already changed it in my code `"rat": "ram", "ram": "mouse"`

Comment: Alternatively, you can make a counter and set the value to something like 200 and put a condition that if the counter reaches 200 `break`, then you can print something like `Hey! this input is not right, there's no end to it..` or anything you like :)

Comment: The infinite loop option was given in the question knowingly to add an option if that happens. I don't know how to keep track of the previous key to compare with the newly iterated value/key. So where exactly I could keep the counter?